# How to specify configuration-specific folder in nuspec

Tags: nuget, nuspec

The examples I've seen specify files to be included using a path relative to the location of the nuspec file, e.g.:

```
<file src=".\bin\Debug\SomeFile.dll" target="..." />
```

Is there a way to specify this in such a way that it will use the appropriate source directory depending on my build configuration: i.e.:

- bin\Debug if I package with -Prop Configuration=Debug
- bin\Release if I package with -Prop Configuration=Release

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use the `$configuration$` token.

**Full Explanation**

In the .nuspec file [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#replacement-tokens), under **Replace Tokens**, it defines the `$configuration$` token as:

> "Configuration used to build the assembly, defaulting to Debug. Note
>   that to create a package using a Release configuration, you always use
>   -properties Configuration=Release on the command line."

And continues with:

> Tokens can also be used to resolve paths when you include assembly
>   files and content files. The tokens have the same names as the MSBuild
>   properties, making it possible to select files to be included
>   depending on the current build configuration.

And then concludes with two examples:

> For example, if you use the following tokens in the .nuspec file:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\$id$.pdb" target="lib\net40\" />
</files>
```

> And you build an assembly whose AssemblyName is LoggingLibrary with
>   the Release configuration in MSBuild, the resulting lines in the
>   .nuspec file in the package is as follows:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\Release\LoggingLibrary.pdb" target="lib\net40" />
</files>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  Not sure how I missed that in the documentation, though the version you linked is very recent (2017-7-25)